# Can a value in a Python Dictionary have two values?

Tags: python, dictionary

For a test program I'm making a simple model of the NFL. I'd like to assign a record (wins and losses) to a team as a value in a dictionary? Is that possible?

For example:

```
afcNorth = ["Baltimore Ravens", "Pittsburgh Steelers", "Cleveland Browns", "Cincinatti Bengals"]
```

If the Ravens had 13 wins and 3 loses, can the dictionary account for both of those values? If so, how?

Comment: The code you've posted is a list of strings, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

sure, just make the value a list or tuple:

```
afc = {'Baltimore Ravens': (10,3), 'Pb Steelers': (3,4)}
```

If it gets more complicated, you might want to make a more complicated structure than a tuple - for example if you like dictionaries, you can put a dictionary in your dictionary so you can dictionary while you dictionary.

```
afc = {'Baltimore Ravens': {'wins':10,'losses': 3}, 'Pb Steelers': {'wins': 3,'losses': 4}}
```

But eventually you might want to move up to classes...

Answer (score 4):

The values in the dictionary can be tuples or, maybe better in this case, lists:

```
d = {"Baltimore Ravens": [13, 3]}
d["Baltimore Ravens"][0] += 1
print d
# {"Baltimore Ravens": [14, 3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use a tuple (or a list):

```
records = {}
records["Baltimore Ravens"] = (13, 3)
```

Or you could be fancy and make a `Record` class with `Record.wins` and `record.losses`, but that's probably overkill.

(As another answer points out, using a list means that you can do arithmetic on the values, which might be useful.)

Comment: You can do arithmetic on any values. Having a list or tuple allows you to easily **iterate over** the values. (And, perhaps, do math with things like `sum()` that do the iteration for you.)